# Passing Pointer to an Object

Tags: pointers

When I pass a pointer (pointing to an object) to a called function as a parameter, why don't the object's attributes get copied? Is there a practical reason why this doesn't happen?

For example, if x is a pointer to an object, then the assignment x=y within the called function is not visible to the calling function. Yet, the assignment x.f=3 is visible (f is an attribute).

Thanks!

Comment: What is the language? C++? Make [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to explain yourself.

Comment: Sorry, this is from the first chapter of "Introduction to Algorithms" by MIT. This is part of the pseudo code rules, so no programming language is specified.

Comment: Different languages have slightly different concepts/rules of *object*, *pointer*, *attributes*, *assignment*, etc.

Comment: Please specify the language; each language uses different conventions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pointer (in c and c++ and most other languages) is variable that points to an adress in memory, where the actual object resides.

1. Assigning one pointer to another just copies that address from one pointer to the other. Passing a pointer `p` to a function, where the corresponding parameter is called `x` results in two pointers pointing to the same address/object: one inside the calling function (`p`) and one inside the called one (`x`), but you still have only one object (`obj1`).
2. Now, `x.f=3` (or `c->f=3` in c/c++ syntax) means:
   "Assign 3 to the attribute f of the object x points to". As this is the same object, `p` points to, you can observe that change also via `p`.
3. However, when you have another pointer `y` inside the function that points to a DIFFERENT object (`obj2`), and you assign that pointer to x, you do not copy the contents of obj2 to obj1, but you are only copying the ADDRESS of obj2 into `x` and leave obj1 unchanged. Now `x` points to a differen object than `p` does and as a result you won't observe any changes via `p` afterwards.